# Wordstrip function skipping words for no apparent reason.

Tags: php, regex, sanitization

Realized tonight that one of the stripping functions I'm using seems to be randomly skipping words.

```
<?php
function wordstrip($document){ 
  //I truncated the list here for brevity
$wordlist = array(
"it39s",
"039",
"the",
"while",
"message");

//convert all uppercase to lower so matches work correctly
$document = strtolower($document);
            foreach($wordlist as $word)

            $document = preg_replace("/\s". $word ."\s/", " ", $document);
            //echo $word;
            //echo $document;
            $nopunc = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', ' ', $document);
            $trimmed = trim($nopunc);
            return $trimmed; 
    }
```

?>

It's skipping the word "the" and I have no clue why.  The list is something like 200 words long and I know its working since it strips out most other words..

I fed it "The Last Letter A Message to George W Bush and Dick Cheney From a Dying Veteran"
and got back "the last letter a to george w bush and dick cheney from a dying veteran"

I think its due to the "/\s" since the "the" is at the beginning of the string.  I tried "/\s?" but that didnt work.   I think I just need to make the spaces optional right?

Thank you

Comment: http://codepad.org/rhBk6PmH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\b` to represent a word boundary and not fiddle with the spaces or periods or whatever else might surround a word:

```
$document = strtolower($document);

foreach($wordlist as $word)
    $document = preg_replace("/\b". $word ."\b/", " ", $document);

$nopunc = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', ' ', $document);
$trimmed = trim($nopunc);
return $trimmed;
```

Comment: Why would you `strtolower()` instead of `/i`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - it's not my code... just using what was asked.

Comment: Ah - didn't notice that in the original. Consider that directed at TheEditor.

Comment: @Daedalus. Thanks. My regex is horrible, I never used /b but that works great.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I just never thought about it really. I'm just happy when I get a statement to actually work but /i would be a much smarter solution. Thanks for that.